# Are Our Favorite Questions Listed Somewhere in Our Profile?

Tags: support

Re. Favorite Questions:

It's not a feature I use often, but I have checked a few - the little gold star just below the voting summary to the left of the question itself.

I assumed a list of the questions we've *starred* as "Favorite Questions" would be kept in our Profile, but I can't find it. Does the SE system maintain a list? If so, where do I find mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everytime I think about where these are I realize I have forgotten again since last time, scour the interface for minutes, then feel like an idiot because it's been staring me in the face.  Then that the question I thought I had starred wasn't starred and I am out of luck anyway.

Select "Activity", upper left (next to "Profile").  Directly below the big boxes summarizing all your rep and badges there's a row of tab links:

> Summary Answers Questions Tags Badges **Favorites** Bounties ....

*[As noted in a comment this has changed to "Bookmarks".]*

Typing <del>"favorites"</del> "bookmarks" in the browser search with the Activity page works if you are really have a hard time of it.

Comment: :) I don't know why I missed that, but thanks Eagle Eye!

Comment: Same here... and what wonders me even more are the items on that list that I must have put on that list for a reason at some point in the distant history.

Comment: "Favorites" has recently been renamed "Bookmarks" with the star having been replaced with a bookmark.

Comment: The "Bookmarks" change is noted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks